# Implementing a multi-CPU FCFS algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm

I'm trying to implement a multi-CPU FCFS algorithm, but I couldn't think of a way to implement on how jobs/processes jump to another CPU.

Can anyone explain to me or give me tips on where to get started?

Here's what I have so far, I tried implementing the FCFS algorithm for a single CPU first:

```
int n, burstTime[99], waitingTime[99], totalAT[99], aveWT = 0, aveTAT = 0, i, j;
cout << "Enter total number of processes: ";
cin >> n;

cout << "\nEnter Process Burst Time\n";
for (i = 0; i<n; i++)
{
    cout << "P[" << i + 1 << "]: ";
    cin >> burstTime[i];
}

waitingTime[0] = 0;    //waiting time for first process is 0

              //calculating waiting time
for (i = 1; i<n; i++)
{
    waitingTime[i] = 0;
    for (j = 0; j<i; j++)
        waitingTime[i] += burstTime[j];
}

cout << "\nProcess\t\tBurst Time\tWaiting Time\tTurnaround Time";

//calculating turnaround time
for (i = 0; i<n; i++)
{
    totalAT[i] = burstTime[i] + waitingTime[i];
    aveWT += waitingTime[i];
    aveTAT += totalAT[i];
    cout << "\nP[" << i + 1 << "]" << "\t\t" << burstTime[i] << "\t\t" << waitingTime[i] << "\t\t" << totalAT[i];
}

aveWT /= i;
aveTAT /= i;
cout << "\n\nAverage Waiting Time: " << aveWT;
cout << "\nAverage Turnaround Time: " << aveTAT <<endl;
```

EDIT:
For example, here's a sample output of what I want to do and implement with the program:

```
    Enter number of CPUs: 2

Enter total number of processes: 6

Enter Process Burst Time
P1: [input here]
P2: [input here]
P3: [input here]
p4: [input here]
p5: [input here]
p6: [input here]

Process     Burst Time         Waiting Time                 Turn Around Time
P1          [burst time here]  [calculated waiting time here]      [calculated turn around time]
P2          [burst time here]  [calculated waiting time here]      [calculated turn around time]
P3          [burst time here]  [calculated waiting time here]      [calculated turn around time]
P4          [burst time here]  [calculated waiting time here]      [calculated turn around time]

 P5          [burst time here]  [calculated waiting time here]      [calculated turn around time]
 P6          [burst time here]  [calculated waiting time here]      [calculated turn around time]


CPUs handling the processes: 
CPU 1: P1, P3, P4
CPU 2: P2, P5, P6
```

Comment: What do you mean with multi-CPU? Are you planning to use threading?

Answer (score 1):

There is one simple approach to parallelizing things. The basic idea is that you split the tasks into independent chunks that are each handled in parallel by a separate thread. This is not always the best suited approach, because in some cases it is simply impossible to split the data into chunks that are also independent.

Anyhow, let's assume that the task can actually be parallelized. For example, let's consider a bunch of data that gets frobnosticated:

```
data = input("some large file")
output = []
for i in length(data):
    output[i] = frobnosticate(data[i])
```

The first step is to split the task into chunks:

```
chunks = 42
data = input("some large file")
chunksize = length(data) / chunks
output = []
for c in chunks:
    # split off one chunk and frobnosticate it
    chunk = data[c * chunksize ... (c + 1) * chunksize]
    tmp = []
    for i in chunk:
        tmp[i] = frobnosticate(chunk[i])
    # store results in the output container
    for i in length(tmp):
        output[c * chunksize + i] = tmp[i]
```

This code should split the data into chunks of equal size and handle these separately. The tricky part here is that it may be impossible to create chunks of equal size. Also, you should make sure you don't copy the input data unnecessarily, especially when it is large. That means that both `chunk` and `tmp` should be proxies rather than containers which just access the data at the correct positions in `data` and `output`. The second inner loop should basically not exist!

As a last step, you then move the execution of the inner loop into a separate thread. First, you start one thread for each CPU, then, you wait for those threads to finish and retrieve the results:

```
chunks = 42
data = input("some large file")
chunksize = length(data) / chunks
output = []
threads = []
for c in chunks:
    # split off one chunk and frobnosticate it in a separate thread
    chunk = data[c * chunksize ... (c + 1) * chunksize]
    threads[c] = create_thread(frobnosticate, chunk)
for c in chunks:
    # wait for one thread to finish and store its results in the output container
    threads[c].join()
    tmp = threads[c].get_result() 
    for i in length(tmp):
        output[c * chunksize + i] = tmp[i]
```

Implementing this in C++ shouldn't be a problem. You can use `std::thread` to run multiple threads that the OS will distribute to the different CPUs automatically. Using different processes doesn't give you any advantage here and rather adds overhead.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry if I couldn't state it clearly, what I want to do is something much simpler, not really something so advanced and complicated as threading. 

I just want to simulate the FCFS algorithm that processes jobs on multiple CPUs.

Here's an example output of what I envisioned:
The program will ask the user to input how many CPUs should process the jobs and then the program proceeds to do the instructions calculating the average waiting time and average turn around time for each process.

Comment: For example: 

`Enter number of CPUs: 2

Enter total number of processes: 6

Enter Process Burst Time
P1: [input here]
P2: [input here]
P3: [input here]
p4: [input here]

CPUs handling the processes: 
CPU 1: P1, P3, P4
CPU 2: P2, P5, P6`